# Анимация при изменении textContent

Tags: javascript, анимация

Возможно ли, как-то при изменении содержимого DOM - узла анимировать процесс этих изменений?
 Допустим, в примере ниже, необходимо, чтобы цифры плавно пропадали/появлялись.

```js
let span = document.querySelector('span');
let i = 0;
setInterval( () => {
  span.textContent = i++;
  },1000);
```

```html
<span></span>
```

Comment: одна на месте другой должна появляться? или как?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
let span = document.querySelector('span');
let i = 0;

setInterval(() => {
  span.textContent = i++;
}, 1000);
```

```css
@keyframes example {
  0% { opacity: 0 }
  50% { opacity: 1 }
  100% { opacity: 0 }
}

span {
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

```html
<span />
```

Comment: Так это не анимация, "при изменении textContent". Это просто - бесконечная анимация  синхронизированная с такими же бесконечными изменениями